# Give column its own row if a cell is longer than a given amount

Tags: tables, tabularx

My document was originally composed with monospace unicode output from a Python terminal. The original layout used blank spaces to align results into columns. I specified the width (in characters) of the columns, if a result was longer than that width, the result would get its own line. Long results include the rows called Mode Info, Mode Jazz, Qualities in the included image.[image]

I decided to wrap the book in LaTeX, and have been making progress on replicating my old layout. Here is the part that is working fairly much like what I want.

[image]

It uses the following tabular:

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l| l|l| l| l| l| l| l}
\\
\hline
Jazz & \cellcolor{C}{1} & \cellcolor{D}{2} & \cellcolor{E}{3} & \cellcolor{F}{4} & \cellcolor{G}{5} & \cellcolor{A}{6} & \cellcolor{B}{7}\\
    Chord & \cellcolor{C}{ma7} & \cellcolor{D}{mi7} & \cellcolor{E}{mi7} & \cellcolor{F}{ma7} & \cellcolor{G}{7} & \cellcolor{A}{mi7} & \cellcolor{B}{⌀7}\\
    Classical & \cellcolor{C}{Ⅰ} & \cellcolor{D}{ⅱ} & \cellcolor{E}{ⅲ} & \cellcolor{F}{Ⅳ} & \cellcolor{G}{Ⅴ} & \cellcolor{A}{ⅵ} & \cellcolor{B}{ⅶ}\\
    Solfege & \cellcolor{C}{Do} & \cellcolor{D}{Re} & \cellcolor{E}{Mi} & \cellcolor{F}{Fa} & \cellcolor{G}{Sol} & \cellcolor{A}{La} & \cellcolor{B}{Ti}\\
    Set & \cellcolor{C}{0} & \cellcolor{D}{2} & \cellcolor{E}{4} & \cellcolor{F}{5} & \cellcolor{G}{7} & \cellcolor{A}{9} & \cellcolor{B}{11}\\
    Notation & \cellcolor{C}{S} & \cellcolor{D}{R2} & \cellcolor{E}{G3} & \cellcolor{F}{M1} & \cellcolor{G}{P} & \cellcolor{A}{D2} & \cellcolor{B}{N3}\\
    Mneumonic & \cellcolor{C}{Sa} & \cellcolor{D}{Ri} & \cellcolor{E}{Gu} & \cellcolor{F}{Ma} & \cellcolor{G}{Pa} & \cellcolor{A}{Di} & \cellcolor{B}{Nu}\\
    Key Of B♯ & \cellcolor{C}{B♯} & \cellcolor{D}{C♯♯} & \cellcolor{E}{D♯♯} & \cellcolor{F}{E♯} & \cellcolor{G}{F♯♯} & \cellcolor{A}{G♯♯} & \cellcolor{B}{A♯♯}\\
    Key Of C & \cellcolor{C}{C} & \cellcolor{D}{D} & \cellcolor{E}{E} & \cellcolor{F}{F} & \cellcolor{G}{G} & \cellcolor{A}{A} & \cellcolor{B}{B}\\
    Key Of C♯ & \cellcolor{Db}{C♯} & \cellcolor{Eb}{D♯} & \cellcolor{F}{E♯} & \cellcolor{Gb}{F♯} & \cellcolor{Ab}{G♯} & \cellcolor{Bb}{A♯} & \cellcolor{C}{B♯}\\
    Key Of D♭ & \cellcolor{Db}{D♭} & \cellcolor{Eb}{E♭} & \cellcolor{F}{F} & \cellcolor{Gb}{G♭} & \cellcolor{Ab}{A♭} & \cellcolor{Bb}{B♭} & \cellcolor{C}{C}\\
    Key Of D & \cellcolor{D}{D} & \cellcolor{E}{E} & \cellcolor{Gb}{F♯} & \cellcolor{G}{G} & \cellcolor{A}{A} & \cellcolor{B}{B} & \cellcolor{Db}{C♯}\\
    Key Of D♯ & \cellcolor{Eb}{D♯} & \cellcolor{F}{E♯} & \cellcolor{G}{F♯♯} & \cellcolor{Ab}{G♯} & \cellcolor{Bb}{A♯} & \cellcolor{C}{B♯} & \cellcolor{D}{C♯♯}\\
    Key Of E♭ & \cellcolor{Eb}{E♭} & \cellcolor{F}{F} & \cellcolor{G}{G} & \cellcolor{Ab}{A♭} & \cellcolor{Bb}{B♭} & \cellcolor{C}{C} & \cellcolor{D}{D}\\
    Key Of E & \cellcolor{E}{E} & \cellcolor{Gb}{F♯} & \cellcolor{Ab}{G♯} & \cellcolor{A}{A} & \cellcolor{B}{B} & \cellcolor{Db}{C♯} & \cellcolor{Eb}{D♯}\\'
    Key Of F♭ & \cellcolor{E}{F♭} & \cellcolor{Gb}{G♭} & \cellcolor{Ab}{A♭} & \cellcolor{A}{B♭♭} & \cellcolor{B}{C♭} & \cellcolor{Db}{D♭} & \cellcolor{Eb}{E♭}\\
    Key Of E♯ & \cellcolor{F}{E♯} & \cellcolor{G}{F♯♯} & \cellcolor{A}{G♯♯} & \cellcolor{Bb}{A♯} & \cellcolor{C}{B♯} & \cellcolor{D}{C♯♯} & \cellcolor{E}{D♯♯}\\
    Key Of F & \cellcolor{F}{F} & \cellcolor{G}{G} & \cellcolor{A}{A} & \cellcolor{Bb}{B♭} & \cellcolor{C}{C} & \cellcolor{D}{D} & \cellcolor{E}{E}\\
    Key Of F♯ & \cellcolor{Gb}{F♯} & \cellcolor{Ab}{G♯} & \cellcolor{Bb}{A♯} & \cellcolor{B}{B} & \cellcolor{Db}{C♯} & \cellcolor{Eb}{D♯} & \cellcolor{F}{E♯}\\
    Key Of G♭ & \cellcolor{Gb}{G♭} & \cellcolor{Ab}{A♭} & \cellcolor{Bb}{B♭} & \cellcolor{B}{C♭} & \cellcolor{Db}{D♭} & \cellcolor{Eb}{E♭} & \cellcolor{F}{F}\\
    Key Of G & \cellcolor{G}{G} & \cellcolor{A}{A} & \cellcolor{B}{B} & \cellcolor{C}{C} & \cellcolor{D}{D} & \cellcolor{E}{E} & \cellcolor{Gb}{F♯}\\
    Key Of G♯ & \cellcolor{Ab}{G♯} & \cellcolor{Bb}{A♯} & \cellcolor{C}{B♯} & \cellcolor{Db}{C♯} & \cellcolor{Eb}{D♯} & \cellcolor{F}{E♯} & \cellcolor{G}{F♯♯}\\
    Key Of A♭ & \cellcolor{Ab}{A♭} & \cellcolor{Bb}{B♭} & \cellcolor{C}{C} & \cellcolor{Db}{D♭} & \cellcolor{Eb}{E♭} & \cellcolor{F}{F} & \cellcolor{G}{G}\\
    Key Of A & \cellcolor{A}{A} & \cellcolor{B}{B} & \cellcolor{Db}{C♯} & \cellcolor{D}{D} & \cellcolor{E}{E} & \cellcolor{Gb}{F♯} & \cellcolor{Ab}{G♯}\\
    Key Of A♯ & \cellcolor{Bb}{A♯} & \cellcolor{C}{B♯} & \cellcolor{D}{C♯♯} & \cellcolor{Eb}{D♯} & \cellcolor{F}{E♯} & \cellcolor{G}{F♯♯} & \cellcolor{A}{G♯♯}\\
    Key Of B♭ & \cellcolor{Bb}{B♭} & \cellcolor{C}{C} & \cellcolor{D}{D} & \cellcolor{Eb}{E♭} & \cellcolor{F}{F} & \cellcolor{G}{G} & \cellcolor{A}{A}\\
    Key Of B & \cellcolor{B}{B} & \cellcolor{Db}{C♯} & \cellcolor{Eb}{D♯} & \cellcolor{E}{E} & \cellcolor{Gb}{F♯} & \cellcolor{Ab}{G♯} & \cellcolor{Bb}{A♯}\\
    Key Of C♭ & \cellcolor{B}{C♭} & \cellcolor{Db}{D♭} & \cellcolor{Eb}{E♭} & \cellcolor{E}{F♭} & \cellcolor{Gb}{G♭} & \cellcolor{Ab}{A♭} & \cellcolor{Bb}{B♭}\\
    Chord  & \cellcolor{C}{191} & \cellcolor{D}{169} & \cellcolor{E}{169} & \cellcolor{F}{191} & \cellcolor{G}{190} & \cellcolor{A}{169} & \cellcolor{B}{165}\\

Step & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
Rhythm & ♩ & ♩ & ♪ & ♩ & ♩ & ♩ & ♪\\
```

However if I include rows with longer results, the table becomes wider than the page (real quick). Is there a way to check the width of the result and then add more rows?

Thanks ahead of time for any insight into this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet -- as usual here -- compilable!

Comment: In particular, please do tell us how the cell colors "C", "D", etc are defined.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Is there a way to check the width of the result and then add more rows?" Are you maybe asking about how to allow automatic line wrapping in a cell?

Comment: your question is not at all clear, you have specified no line breaking in each cell (`l`) you could have cells which linebreak (`p{1cm}` or you could allow page breaking between rows (`longtable`) but how does one cell having too much data get translated into having more rows?